# Добавление кода в нативные функции

Tags: javascript

Как можно добавить немного своего кода в функцию (не свою, а `[native code]`).

Пример кода:

```
Math.__defineGetter__('pow', function() {
    console.log( 'USE: Math.pow' );
    return function() { return 100500; };
});
```

То есть при вызове `Math.pow(1,2);` в консоль пишется `'USE: Math.pow'` и возвращается `100500`.

Надо сделать так, чтобы функция писала в консоль и продолжала свою "правильную" работу.

Я пишу "юзерскрипт" и хочу знать какие методы использует сайт. Не все, конечно, а, например, только из `Math`.

```
for (var i in Math ) {
    eval('Math.__defineGetter__( "' + i + '", function() { console.log( "USE Math.' + i + '" ); return 1; });');
}
```

Сейчас я могу это узнать, в консоль всё пишет, но функции не работают и вызывают ошибки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Простой пример с `Math.pow()` для демонстрации идеи:

```js
var savedPow = Math.pow;
Math.pow = function(number, exp) {
    console.log('USE: Math.pow');
    return savedPow(number, exp);
};

console.log(Math.pow(10, 3));
```

Comment: Спасибо :) Буду делать исходя из Вашего кода!

Comment: @wolter_white на здоровье. `for (var key in Math ) { ... }` у меня почему-то не работает, поэтому полный пример не сделаю. Единственное что могу ещё сказать - вместо передачи `number` и `exp` можно в `saved` передавать просто массив `arguments`. [Пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qcr8t4mv/1/). Так сказать, универсальный вариант для всех функций.

Comment: Лучше никогда не забывать про прототайп.